# GameTheory, Solve for optimal strategies by solving a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-programming, game-theory

In a book on game theory I saw the following example of a game, a modified version of Roshambo (or Rock-paper-scissors), which is described by the following payoff-matrix:
$$
 \begin{array}{c|c|c}
   0 & -1 & +1 \\ \hline
   +1 & 0 & -2 \\ \hline
   -1 & +2 & 0
  \end{array}
$$
To solve this game, the book proceeds as follow. Say the strategy of the first player will be $\{ a,b,c \}$. Then he wants to make the EV of the second player from the varios strategy options equal. For the different selections (columns) of the seconds player we got the following EVs for the first player:

First column: $0\cdot a + 1\cdot b + (-1)\cdot c = b - c$

Second column: $(-1)\cdot a + 0\cdot b + 2\cdot c = 2c - a$

Third column: $1\cdot a + (-2)\cdot b + 0 \cdot c = a - 2b$

Equating the above equations yields:
$$
  b - c = 2c - a = a - 2b
$$
and with the restriction $a+b+c=1$, the system of equations
\begin{align*}
  b - c & = 2c - a \\
2c - a & = a - 2b \\
a + b + c & = 1
\end{align*}
results, which has the solution $a = 1/2, b = 1/4, c = 1/4$.

Now I wanted to generalise the above solution technique and wanted to apply it to the following modified version of the above game.
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\ \hline
 -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\ \hline
 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
 1 & 1 & -1 & 0
\end{array}
$$
Let ${a,b,c,d}$ a mixed strategy for the first player, and regardless of which strategy player two chooses, the EV should be equal. So I calculated the EVs for the four different pure strategies of player two and equated them.

Player two selects first column: $0\cdot a + (-1)\cdot b + 1\cdot c + 1\cdot d = -b + c + d$

Second column: $a - c + d$

Third column: $-a + b - d$

Fourth column: $-a -b + c$

Equating them and introducing the additional restriction $a+b+c+d = 1$, I get the following system of equations:
\begin{align*}
a + b - 2c &= 0 \\
2a + b - 2c + d &= 0 \\
2b - c - d &= 0 \\
a + b + c + d &= 1
\end{align*}
which has no solution???? But I read also (called the fundamental theorem) that every matrix game has a solution??? So I am confused, but I can't spot if I made an error?

EDIT: Changed "Third column: $-a + b - d$" to "Third column: $-a + b + d$".

EDIT: The Game Matrix was wrong, in the third column the last entry should be "-1", not "1". Changed this, now the third column again reads: $-a + b - d$.

Comment: I think "Third column: $−a+b-d$" should be "Third column: $−a+b+d$".

Comment: Or something is wrong with the matrix in row 4 column 3.

Comment: Also, you are assuming that a solution must be a strong mixture of four actions. It could also consist of less than four actions.

Comment: @Gugg: Guess I need to consider all possible *four* actions of the second player...

Comment: Where did $2b-c-d=0$ come from?  If it is equating the third and fourth column equations I think it should be $2b-c+d=0$  But then the first two give $a+d=0$

Comment: The game matrix was wrong! Now it should be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out in a comment, you're making the unwarranted assumption that the expected values of all of the opponent's moves must be equal. Only the expected values of the moves to which the opponent's mixed strategy assigns positive probability must be equal. That's because if they weren't, the opponent could shift probability from a worse move to a better move; but she can't shift probability away from a move that already has zero probability.

Comment: can you give an example? I equate all possible moves (pure strategys) from the opponent, because I am searching a strategy for which the opponent should be indifferent, so I need to set them all equal and solve them, I don't understand why this is not allowed?

Comment: @Stefan: Sorry I didn't respond to this comment; I hope my answer to [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324688) has helped to clear things up? (I'm not sure what you were asking for an example of -- both of your questions themselves already afford examples of this phenomenon.)

Answer (score 2):

Since the games you are describing are of two-player zero-sum, it is good to know that the value of the game is zero. The value exists because the game is finite, so both players have optimal strategies which guarantee this value. Moreover, the game is symmetric, so both players have the same optimal strategies. 
Moreover, because the players have even number of actions, then there is theorem saying that there is no optimal strategy which assigns positive probability to each action. So Gugg's intuition is right in this sense.

Keeping those in mind, I see that you are making a mistake in the first line; ($-b + c + d$). Because this action is played with probability 0. Then we consider those equations only:

\begin{align*}
2a + b - 2c + d &= 0 \\
2b - c - d &= 0 \\
a + b + c + d &= 1
\end{align*}

so the unique solution is $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3})$. As a result the unique optimal strategy is $(0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3})$.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't know about such a theorem. I only noticed that row/column $1$ are the only weakly dominated strategies.

Comment: Let me put a reference if I can find:) (I probably remember this from a class).